# Why is asking about potato futures considered "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This seems like a fairly straightforward set of questions to me:  [What does it mean to invest in potatoes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48573/what-does-it-mean-to-invest-in-potatoes)

The OP is asking how one can trade a potato on an exchange.  His/her puzzlement stems from not knowing:

1. How to handle the differences among potatoes (unlike a typical stock certificate of company ABC)
2. How futures trading works

What is the rationale behind tagging the question as "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: Personally I think it's quite a reasonable question and I've now reopened it. I waited for it to accumulate a couple of other reopen votes so it wasn't just my binding vote overriding everyone else. It also got another "Leave open" from the original Close review.

Hopefully we'll hear from someone who was on the "Close" side of the fence.

Comment: Great work.  The community has decided.Turns out that kind of fundamental understanding is important information our site will teach.  Thanks for bringing it up.